# How to pass argument to SSI include directive?

Tags: ssi

Is there a better way to include a file and pass some arguments to it?

I am using this:

```
<!--#set var="title" value="Homepage" -->
<!--#include file="../includes/header.shtml" -->
```

But it doesn't work if you want to include the file multiple times in the same page with different titles.

Something like this would be nice:

```
<!--#include file="../includes/header.shtml" title="Homepage" -->
```

Unfortunately, it doesn't work.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1):

Try using virtual includes not files includes :

```
<!--#set var="title" value="Appel" -->
<!--#include virtual="/includes/static/appel_a_temoins_form.html" -->
```

But your first code should work.
Just set your vars before your includes files...